# Shutdown only shuts down on the second attempt

Tags: shutdown

My Lenovo Thinkpad W530 is running Ubuntu 16.4 and since the last few days it only shuts down on the second attempt, and then it then does shut down. 
I've tried "sudo poweroff" in the Terminal as against the GUI with the same results.
Any ideas please?
Garoolgan

Comment: Last night for the first time in a week my laptop shut down on the first attempt all on its' own! Maybe it though better of bothering me in view of some ideas, one of you might have had to rectify the situation?!  I'll keep you posted in case of change of heart on the part of my laptop.

Comment: FYI-= that was the only time my laptop shut down on the first attempt and it kept going back to twice until this evening when a geeky guy at my local Linux club (once a month) cleaned the laptop up. Now it shuts down OK.

Comment: It started its' 2 x shut down again a couple of days after the Linux club intervention. I am now waiting on the next meeting on next Friday with a new SSD HD (240Gb) and I will hopefully then have a new clean install. I've been lent a SATA to USB cable to bring back my data from what must be a bad HDD.

Comment: The new clean install brought me back to a normal shutdown. What I'm not even trying to understand is why it always shut down on the second attempt but never on the first?!!?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried turning off different applications before shutting down and it turned out that certain application (in my case - GoldenDict) was causing the problem, so I just removed it from autostart. You can try the same approach to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Roman for your answer. Since wiping everything and installing 20.04 LTS I've had no problems with multiple shutdowns.